# The server is returning that the request is bad, but my simple post looks correct

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I've got a fairly simple straightforward post I am trying to send to the server that controls a printer.  Ultimately it's for a asp.net web application, but figured I should dumb it down first.

Using the Postman app I can submit the job to the printer with the following:

Post:  127.0.0.1:8083/rxlabelprint

```
Body:
{   
     "name": "Natalie D Sanderson",
    "dob": "08/05/2009",                            
    "directions": "Take twice daily",     
    "med-details": "Amox 500mg",              
    "dry-run": "True"                               
}
```

This works great!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string content = "{'name': 'Natalie D Sanderson', 'dob': '08/05/2009', 'directions': 'Take twice daily', 'med-details': 'Amox 500mg','dry-run': 'True'}";
            var result = client.PostAsync(
                "http://localhost:8083/rxlabelprint",
         new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            string resultContent = result.Result.ToString();  // Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Error Message:

StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'BAD REQUEST', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2019 21:31:17 GMT
  Server: nginx/1.15.8
  Content-Length: 92
  Content-Type: application/json
}

Comment: Json is formatted with `"` double quotes, not `'` single quotes.

Comment: And for future reference, a site like https://jsonlint.com can help you validate your JSON. In general though you should not be building it by hand like that as a string - instead create an object in C# then use a serialiser to generate JSON from it - that will guarantee you always get valid JSON

Comment: Please stop trying to assemble JSON (or XML or SQL or CSV or any other text data format) via string concatenation; that is the slowest and most error-prone way of doing it. Use a JSON (or XML or whatever) parser, a JSON file or resource that can do validation, has intellisense, and so much more.

Comment: I knew about the double quotes, and was trying to do things properly but quickly, hence the hand-formatted JSON.  I was thinking that the StringContent Method would likely handle the conversion, since C# likes double quotes for the strings and would get confused having double quotes in a string?  Or would I just need to double up the delimiters and still use double quotes.

Comment: You'd have to escape the double quotes in the string with backslashes. But just... don't. Use a proper serialiser (e.g. JSON.NET). It won't slow you down. Or send the data in url-encoded format, as per the answer below, if the server accepts that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to Post, but otherwise the comment was great!  Here is my final answer:

```
    var targeturi = "http://localhost:8083/rxlabelprint";
    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

    HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "Natalie Sanderson"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dob", "08/05/2005"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("directions", "Take twice daily"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("med-details", "Amox 500mg"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dry-run", "False")
    });

    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
    var result = client.PostAsync(targeturi, content).Result;
    string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //log response
    Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Send a reliable request by formatting your parameters using [FormUrlEncodedContent](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/System.Net.Http/FormUrlEncodedContent/-/php-formurlencodedcontent-class-examples.html) which is readily available for you

```
        var targeturi = "http://localhost:8083/rxlabelprint"
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "Natalie D Sanderson"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dob", "08/05/2009"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("directions", "Take twice daily"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("med-details", "Amox 500mg"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dry-run", "True")
        });

        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
        var result = await client.GetAsync(targeturi, content);
        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //log response
        Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Looks just like what I was looking for!  I'll give it a try as soon as I get home from work tomorrow.  Thanks!